# Creating a dynamic table in html for a firefox extention

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, firefox-addon, dynamic-typing

I tried using:

```
<form>
   <button>Save ID</button>
</form>

<script>   
   var table = '';
   var rows = 10;
   var columns = 3;
   for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) 
   {
        table += '<tr>';
        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            table += '<td>' + c + '</td>';
        }
        table += '</tr>';   
   }

   document.write('<table border=1>' + table + '</table>');   
</script>
```

It worked as a normal html page but when I try to load it in an extension it only shows the button.

I want to load data from a file and use it to fill the table later on.

Edit:

My manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "IDSaver",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "32": "icons/testExt.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/testExt.png",
    "default_title": "IDSaver",
    "default_popup": "popup/IDSaverPopup.html"
  }
}
```

I don't know a lot about the manifest stuff so I don't know if the problem is in there.

Comment: How are you loading it in your extension? I'd also advise you not to use document.write (I'm pretty sure it will even raise some flags when you'll try to publish your extension to AMO), check https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement and methods to insert those elements into DOM.

Comment: I tried using createElement now but it still won't show in the extension popup.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found my problem.
You can't write the script inside of the html file itself.
I had to make a .js file with the code and use  inside the html file to make it work.